# How to stop Chrome filling other form entries when using autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

Everytime I use the autocomplete function in Chrome it changes/updates many other fields, is there any way to stop this and use the autocomplete only on the current field?

For example, if I use autocomplete on "email" field, Chrome will update also the "name" field, "address" field, "phone" field etc with previous entries, even if I already filled those fields ! it's really annoying